# Python uninstall woes

Tags: python, ubuntu, ctypes

I was setting up my first Python package as described [here](http://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/creation.html) and it seemed necessary to get Python 2.7.13 to finish. Not realizing how integral Python 2.7.12 was to Ubuntu's health, I moved 2.7.12 dirs (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/) to backup dirs and replaced them with 2.7.13 dirs and removed python3. This led to a series of problems which eventually killed my desktop (no launcher, no alt-t terminal) which after a lengthy battle required me to alt-F1 into a non-GUI terminal, undo the directory swaps, and as detailed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/removed-python-3-and-now-ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications) after

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7
sudo apt-get install python3-all
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

things are now nearly normal except I can't reinstall pip (to use ipython amongst others) due to a lacking ctypes. I'm willing to reinstall Ubuntu but only if I really have to.

```
jeremy@jr:~$ python 
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: No module named _ctypes
```

The current state of affairs as far as I know how to check:

```
jeremy@jr:~$ echo $PYTHONHOME
/usr/local/lib/python2.7:/usr/local/lib/python2.7.12
jeremy@jr:~$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/usr/local/lib/python2.7:/usr/local/lib/python2.7.12:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/home/jeremy/sw/caffe/python:/home/jeremy/sw/models/slim:/home/jeremy/sw/models:/home/jeremy/sw/models/utils:
jeremy@jr:~$ which python 
/usr/bin/python
jeremy@jr:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Aug 17 23:37 /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Dec 10  2015 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3546104 Nov 19  2016 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Nov 19  2016 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Dec 10  2015 /usr/bin/python2-config -> python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Mar 23  2016 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.5
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4460336 Nov 17  2016 /usr/bin/python3.5
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4460336 Nov 17  2016 /usr/bin/python3.5m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Mar 23  2016 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.5m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Dec 10  2015 /usr/bin/python-config -> python2.7-config
```

/usr/local/lib/python2.7 looks OK, with a bunch of scripts from _abcoll.py to zipfile.pyc.

pip is also broken , giving the error

```
jeremy@jr:/usr/src/Python-2.7.12$ pip install ctypes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

which

```
jeremy@jr:/usr/src/Python-2.7.12$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-pkg-resources
```

does not fix (same error above occurs after reinstall)

The question is, how do I fix my apparently somewhat-broken python install, to fix ctypes, pip, and any other potentially-missing parts?

```
jeremy@jr:~$ ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/ctypes/
_endian.py  _endian.pyc  __init__.py  __init__.pyc  macholib  test  util.py  util.pyc  wintypes.py  wintypes.pyc
```

Comment: Why not directly unpack the package files into filesystem? I have done so a couple of times when recovering from severe corruption. Never had a single issue after that.

Comment: @coldspeed, question is, how to fix the ctypes problem and any further ones that may be lurking

Comment: @user1643723, can you fill me in on how to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

You've reinstalled one of the packages that have things in /usr/lib/python, but not all of them. ctypes in particular is in libpython2.7-stdlib. You can ask the package manager what was there and reinstall it all with something like (scary combination ahead):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall `dpkg -S /usr/lib/python2.7 | sed -e 's%: /usr/lib/python2.7%%' -e 's%, % %g'`
```

In general, don't go modifying system directories like /usr without the package manager's assistance. It messes up the system's idea of what's there or not. There are paths for your own installations, like /opt and /usr/local. In this case it appears you're lucky apt even still works.

Also, I find it rather unlikely that you needed specifically 2.7.13 over 2.7.12; more likely it was another portion, such as python-setuptools or python2.7-dev. Ubuntu inherits a rather fine grained split of the Python system from Debian.

It is possible with apt to [pin](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) particular packages to alternate sources. For instance, it is likely possible to have a hybrid of Ubuntu Xenial with Python packages from Zesty to get 2.7.13.

Comment: "In this case it appears you're lucky apt even still works", — apt is actually rather robust and does not have direct dependencies on python packages. Now, if the issue in question happened on Gentoo, where the package manager itself is written in Python…

Comment: Thanks @yann but after the apt-get install of : (python-setuptools python-pyorbit python-gnome2 python-gi python-wheel python2.7 python-pkg-resources python-pip lsb-release python-tk python-tz unity-lens-photos gir1.2-accounts-1.0), the ctypes error still occurs

Comment: I would've expected that list to include libpython2.7-stdlib which contains ctypes in Debian. Of course, there's a similar set for Python 3. As for apt, usually apt works (though if necessary one can do all of apt and dpkg work with gzip, tar and ar) but it can easily get stuck on a particular package not configuring properly and such.

Comment: those seem to already be in place: jeremy@jr:~$ sudo apt-get install libpython2.7 libpython2.7-stdlib libpython2.7-dev 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libpython2.7 is already the newest version (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1).
libpython2.7-dev is already the newest version (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1).
libpython2.7-stdlib is already the newest version (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.

Comment: upgrading the 4 not-upgraded packages (apt-list --updateable to find the updateable ones, then apt-get upgrade libmircommon-dev, linux-generic, linux-headers-generic, linux-image-generic) also did not avail

Comment: The `--reinstall` portion is *critical*. You've been removing parts of packages which the package manager *still expects to be installed*. The issue is that *seems to* be installed doesn't mean it's *intact*. The package `debsums` can help identify that difference.

Comment: I've realized the problem with that `cut` line. It will cut on colon, which also occurs to select architectures. So it would produce incomplete lists. Replacing with a better sed command.

Comment: I tried the new sed version which result in a reinstall of: (unity-lens-photos python2.7 python-tz python-wheel python-pyorbit python-pkg-resources python-tk python-setuptools python-gnome2 python-gi gir1.2-accounts-1.0:amd64 lsb-release python-pip libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64 libpython2.7-dev:amd64 libpython2.7:amd64 python-vte python-notify python-keybinder python-gconf python-dbus gir1.2-unity-5.0:amd64 gir1.2-signon-1.0 gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64 gir1.2-dee-1.0 python-talloc python-pil:amd64 python-glade2  etc (too many chars))  - but the problem of no _ctypes (or ctypes.py ) remains...

Comment: I tried (sudo debsums|grep -v OK|grep -v REPLACED) and got (debsums: missing file /usr/share/doc/flex/NEWS.gz (from flex package)
debsums: missing file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstopencv.so (from gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64 package)
/usr/share/applications/code.desktop                                      FAILED
/usr/share/doc/libkmod2/changelog.Debian.gz                               FAILED
)  other than a bunch of opencv fails . I reinstallled libgstreamer1.0-plugins-bad just to see if that would fix the debsum, which it did, but of course the ctypes problem remains.

Comment: I can't even begin to guess how those got corrupted, but you might want to try concentrating on one issue. Having reinstalled libpython2.7-stdlib my next guess would be that you're setting PYTHONHOME, overriding where Python looks for its library. Test with `python -E -c "import ctypes"`. Also check if you're running the Python interpreter you expect with `which python`.

Comment: At this point the `python -E -c "import ctypes"`  doesnt return anything (since the problem was fixed, the import is fine and nothing gets printed, but that wouldve been good while the problem was still kicking) .  I checked  `which python` in the question body as well as checking what that was symlinked to ; as you suggest,  the python binary doesnt tell the whole story (library location was the problem , not binary).  In any case thanks for all the help, I'm glad to see the apt-get mechanisms were all fine even after my various uninstalls/reinstalls

Answer (score 0):

solved, by unsetting $PYTHONPATH - from some hints [here](https://leemendelowitz.github.io/blog/how-does-python-find-packages.html) on differences between ubuntu's default  python and 'vanilla python' it seems that having set $PYTHONPATH in the only way that was allowing python to run

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

(/usr/local/lib and not /usr/lib) I blv was actually also preventing the vanilla python from running.

sys.path before unset PYTHONPATH:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib/python2.7
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynloa
```

sys.path after unset PYTHONPATH:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(sys.path))

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stevedore-1.15.0-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/enum34-1.1.6-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pbr-1.10.0-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIMS-0.3.3+105.g1040b5f-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/slicerator-0.9.8-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client
```

Doing the unset PYTHONPATH solved the problem (after of course all the other steps to rebuild desktop, specifically:

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7
```

)